# datetime function in php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I  want to store the data and time in my MYSQL db.I have a datetime field in my db
I want to store current datatime in my db
How shold i get the current date time?How to pass it to db via a sql query

How can i then retriev an print it in correct yyyy--dd--mm format or any other format
What wil be format of time? wil it be 23 hrs etc?
How do i print date and time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming table named 'items' and field named 'modified' of type 'timestamp'

```
$r = mysql_query("INSERT INTO items (modified, x, ...) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, $x, ...)");
// (or "UPDATE items SET modified=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, x=$x, ...)
...

$r = mysql_query("SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(modified) FROM items");
$item = mysql_fetch_assoc($r);
$formatted_ts = date('g:ia', $item['modified']); // or another format *
```

you'll need to add appropriate error-checking which I've omitted; also need to adjust for consideration of timezones, which I've also left out

- see [date()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 3):

You can let MySQL determine the current timestamp by using [Now()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) in your query.

```
INSERT INTO foo (dtfield) VALUES (Now())
```

This can also be done with a [default value for a TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/timestamp.html) field in your table definition

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id int auto_increment,
  creationTime TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  v int,
  primary key(id)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use MySQL's built in date/time functions if you only want to insert it into the MySQL database.

Have a look at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Otherwise, you can use the PHP's [date()](http://www.php.net/date) function.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to set your timezone.